# addBatch() used together with autoCommit = true

Tags: java, jdbc

I have a situation like this :

```
con.setAutoCommit(true);
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
stmt.addBatch(query);//add all the queries
stmt.executeBatch();
```

Will each query commit separately or there will be a single commit for the entire batch?

Note : The database is Oracle 11

Comment: Why are you using autoCommit if you intend to use batches?

Comment: @Kayaman : Its a legacy code.

Answer (score 12):

According to the JDBC specification the exact behavior of a batch execute with auto-commit enabled is implementation defined. So it depends on the database and its driver, and it is better to not make assumptions on the exact behavior and disable auto-commit when using batch executes.

*JDBC 4.1, section 14.1.1* says:

> The commit behavior of `executeBatch` is always implementation-defined when an error occurs and auto-commit is true.

This only says something about the behavior for error conditions, but the implication is that individual statements might already have been committed when another statement in the batch throws an exception.

Answer (score 6):

From [oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html) :

> When a connection is created, it is in auto-commit mode. **This means that each individual SQL statement is treated as a transaction and is automatically committed right after it is executed.** (To be more precise, the default is for a SQL statement to be committed when it is completed, not when it is executed. A statement is completed when all of its result sets and update counts have been retrieved. In almost all cases, however, a statement is completed, and therefore committed, right after it is executed.)

So you'll get commit after each query.

Answer (score 3):

Every query will commit, for single commit turn off auto commit and commit after executeBatch()

```
con.setAutoCommit(false);
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
stmt.addBatch(query);//add all the queries
stmt.executeBatch();
con.commit();
```