# Inserting batches of elements to a database

Tags: java, mysql, sql

So i try to input all the keys from a HashMap to a database. My first approach was to insert all the keys one by one to my database. Note that the HashMap size is some million keys long so this process took a lot of time.

I did some research and stumbled upon the **preparedStatement** interface. So i came up with this piece of code to create a Batch of 10000 elements and then input them all together to the database.

```
final int batchSize = 10000;
int count = 0;
Connection dbConnection = null;
try {
    dbConnection = getDBConnection();
    String SQL = "INSERT INTO masterdict (window) " +
                 "VALUES(?)";

    PreparedStatement ps = (PreparedStatement) dbConnection.prepareStatement(SQL);

    for (String k : masterDict.keySet()) {
        ps.setString(1,k);
        ps.addBatch();
        if(++count % batchSize == 0) {
            System.out.println(count);
            ps.executeBatch();
        }
    }
    ps.executeBatch();
    ps.close();
    dbConnection.close();
```

for some reason though this approach takes exactly the same time to complete as the first one. Can anyone explain to me why is this the case?

Comment: The overhead is probably caused by transactions and not by parsing the SQL string.  You should wrap this in transactions that do multiple inserts at the same time.

Comment: According to the below post it is advised to set  `dbConnection.setAutoCommit(false) ` for batch processing to disable auto commits to the database. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19536513/addbatch-used-together-with-autocommit-true

Comment: Thank you both for you comments. I tried setting setAutoCommit to false. Now the loop is a lot faster but my database ends up being empty :)

Comment: you have to commit the transaction(s) at the end.

Comment: @Jakumi thank you it works perfectly . Should i edit my question to include the final version of the code that works now?

Comment: don't edit, post the working version as an answer and accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading through the comments i ended up with this new version of the code that works just fine.

```
final int batchSize = 10000;
    int count = 0;
    Connection dbConnection = null;
    try {
        dbConnection = getDBConnection();
        String SQL = "INSERT INTO masterdict (window) " +
                 "VALUES(?)";

        PreparedStatement ps = (PreparedStatement) dbConnection.prepareStatement(SQL);
        dbConnection.setAutoCommit(false);
        for (String k : masterDict.keySet()) {
            ps.setString(1,k);
            ps.addBatch();
            if(++count % batchSize == 0) {
                System.out.println(count);
                ps.executeBatch();
                dbConnection.commit();
            }
        }
        ps.executeBatch();
        dbConnection.commit();
        ps.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        if (dbConnection != null) {
            dbConnection.rollback();
        }
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    } finally {
        dbConnection.close();
    }
```

Comment: You should `rollback` in your `catch` block at the end of your `try` (if `dbConnection` is not null).

Also, you should probably `close` the connection in a `finally` block so you don't leak connections in case of exceptions.